# django raw sql - json params not being executed as expected - syntax error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I execute rawsql within a django app (pgsql 9.6 backend) like so:

```
obj=AddModel.objects.raw("""
SELECT * FROM "codeaddmodel" \
WHERE ("codeaddmodel"."data" -> 'CodeData') \
@> '[{"street": "New Street" }]'
""")
```

and it works brilliantly.

Now, I do the following, as per the django doc, and use params:

```
term="New Street"

obj=AddModel.objects.raw("""
SELECT * FROM "codeaddmodel" \
WHERE ("codeaddmodel"."data" -> 'CodeData') \
@> '[{"street": %s }]'
""",[term])
```

and this throws the error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "New"
```

I have tried for around two hours and google has failed me!

Comment: From my understanding you should wrap the placeholder `%s` in `""`: `..{"street": "%s" }..`

Comment: @schwobaseggl The whole point of using placeholders is that you should not need to manually quote anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use a placeholder inside a literal:

```
In [12]: cur.execute("""select ('[{"street": %s}]')::json""", ('New Street',))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-dd23cc772072> in <module>()
----> 1 cur.execute("""select ('[{"street": %s}]')::json""", ('New Street',))

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "New"
LINE 1: select ('[{"street": 'New Street'}]')::json
```

The result is a literal, followed by the key words `New` and `Street`, and another literal. Note how this could open up the venue for SQL injections:

```
In [42]: cur.execute("""select ('[{"street": %s}]')""",
    ...:             (""") = \' OR true OR \' = (""",))
```

so don't manually quote around placeholders. Instead you should replace the whole value with a placeholder and pass a suitable value, in this case a JSON string:

```
obj=AddModel.objects.raw("""
SELECT * FROM "codeaddmodel"
WHERE ("codeaddmodel"."data" -> 'CodeData')
@> %s
""", [json.dumps([{'street': term}])])
```

or if using psycopg2 and Django's raw simply passes values through, [`psycopg2.extras.Json()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation)

Comment: @llja@ absolute genius - yes, I was using a placeholder within a string literal and hence the problems. I am now using the json dumps as you suggested and it works beautifully. Just as a side note, could you post an example of how psycopg2.extras.Json() could be used? I tried to get through the documentation, but it is not clear what I need to import to use psycopg..

Comment: Just put the psycopg part there in case you happen to be using it underneath and Django's `raw()` simply passes through params. If that's the case, `from psycopg2.extras import Json` and instead of `json.dumps` wrap the desired value with `Json()`: `[Json([{'street': term}])]`. In the end they both work pretty much the same.

Comment: @llja@ thanks a tonne again for your super detailed answer and the explanation. Accepted your answer.