# PostgreSQL document based in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql

based on business requirement, we need to get the data from PostgreSQL document based database in python

PostgreSQL:

```
select info from "spyConfig" where info @> '{"type" : "processmap"}';
```

its working as expected in postgresql interface, same query i want to execute in python.

```
cur.execute("SELECT info FROM spyConfig WHERE info @> %s", 
{'type':'processmap'})
```

its not working in python, even i want to pass table as parameter, i have tried here and research on it but its not working in python.
please give me suggestion to solve this and let me know if any details to add here, i will update as need, Thanks.

Comment: @veeram please help on this

Comment: in one you select `info` and in the other you use `id`. Maybe there is a problem with curly brace escaping?

Comment: Practically a duplicate of [psycopg2 insert python dictionary as json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796332/psycopg2-insert-python-dictionary-as-json/31796487), [Create/Insert Json in Postgres with requests and psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747766/create-insert-json-in-postgres-with-requests-and-psycopg2)

Comment: Somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407488/django-raw-sql-json-params-not-being-executed-as-expected-syntax-error

Comment: ^^ I would say that one is pretty much spot on to what he needs as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not passing your dictionary the right way, you should be passing it like this:

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json

cur.execute("SELECT info FROM spyConfig WHERE info @> %s", [Json({'type':'processmap'})])
```

If you want to add the table name also then

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
from psycopg2.extras import Json

kwargs = {'table': AsIs('spyConfig'),
          'q': [Json({'type':'processmap'})]}

cur.execute("SELECT info FROM %(table)s WHERE info @> %(q)s", kwargs)
```

Comment: cur.execute("SELECT info FROM %s WHERE info @> %s", ["spyConfig", Json({'type':'processmap'})])

i am getting below error:
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'spyConfig'"
in the postgresql data base created a table as "spyConfig" with quotes